# Installing numpy for Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to install numpy-1.9.2 for Python 2.7.10, installed it using command prompt using 'setup.py install'. Seems like everything has worked but when I try and import numpy I get error saying "No module named numpy"

Comment: numpy can be annoying to install if you don't use the installer, look at using pip and the wheels packages if you can because they will not need a compiler to install it.

Comment: This can have multiple possible causes; It could be that your *default* `python` is not 2.7. In that case try `python2.7 setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1):

As @gurpinars said, try:

```
pip install numpy
```

in console. It will install the most recent version. Or you can write:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

to upgrade to the newer version.

Answer (score -1):

I generally just avoid the whole numpy install process by using the Anaconda distribution from [Continuum.io](http://continuum.io/). No, I am not a paid spokesperson, haha. But in reality, whether you use anaconda or even the Enthought distribution, this is a lot easier than trying to install these packages with pip.